# Katoolin: command not found

Tags: katoolin

I have followed the [instruction to Install Katoolin](http://linuxpitstop.com/install-kali-linux-tools-on-ubuntu-and-centos/), but this happens:

```
# sudo katoolin
sudo: katoolin: command not found
```

I have searched hard on the net with no joy. What am I doing wrong? I have a Macbook Pro Early 2011 i7 processor.

Comment: Please check whether you successfully copied `katoolin.py` to `/usr/bin`, renamed it and gave it the proper permissions. You can do that with `ls -l /usr/bin/katoolin*`. Please add the output of this command to your question.

Comment: >-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   659 Oct 22 19:29 Changelog.txt
>drwxr-xr-x 3 root root  4096 Oct 27 23:18 katoolin
>-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 51305 Oct 27 23:25 katoolin.py
>-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 18047 Oct 22 19:29 LICENSE
>-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  1231 Oct 22 19:29 README.md

Comment: Did you maybe copy the whole `katoolin` *folder* to `/usr/bin`? You were supposed to only copy `katoolin.py` there and name the file `katoolin`.

Comment: @HenningKockerbeck  so should i just deleat the ther files?

Comment: Best delete the whole `katoolin` folder. Then put only `katoolin.py` directly in `/usr/bin`, not in a sub directory of it, name it `katoolin` and give it the correct permisson as shown in the tutorial you linked.

Comment: It seems that the superfluous sub dir was the root of the problem, so I've written an "official" answer to that effect :)

Answer (score 1):

Judging from the comments to the question, you placed the `katoolin` executable not directly into `/usr/bin`, but in a subdirectory of it.

When you enter a command, the system searches in a number of directories for a matching executable file. If you for example type `foo`, the system looks for `/bin/foo`, `/sbin/foo`, `/usr/bin/foo` and so on. The first such file that is found gets executed. Which directories get searched is defined in the environment variable `PATH`.

But the system does not search in sub directories of the directories listed in `PATH`. Therefore, if you put the `katoolin` executable to, say, `/usr/bin/katoolin/katoolin` instead of `/usr/bin/katoolin`, it won't be found.

Additionally, the executable must have the correct permissions ( `sudo chmod +x /usr/bin/katoolin` ) and the correct name. If you type `katoolin`, for example `/usr/bin/katoolin.py` won't be found either.